# Export from /node_module and ./someFile treated different?

Tags: javascript, npm, import, webpack

I've just moved some components I use in multiple projects to a private NPM module. For some reason though my build process is now generating the following errors for all the components that were moved:

> Module parse failed:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wizer\packages\wizer-atoms\components\Textarea\index.js
>   Unexpected token (7:21) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type.

Do all NPM modules need to be transpiled by default? Because I did not change any thing to the content. And moving the file back resolves the error.

**Example component**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import classnames from "classnames";

class Textarea extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        const { className, ...otherProps } = this.props;

        return <textarea className={classnames("FORM__textfield", className)} />;
    }
}

export default Textarea;
```

**My `index.js` file of the NPM module**

```
const req = require.context(".", true, /\.\/components\/[^/]+\/index\.js/);

req.keys().forEach((key) => {
    const componentName = key.replace(/^.+\/([^/]+)\/index\.js/, "$1");
    module.exports[componentName] = req(key).default;
});
```

This basically takes all files in the `components` directory and exports it. This allows me to use `import { Textarea } from wizer-atoms;`.

Comment: You have ES6 modules and import/export which is not currently supported in your environment. Yes you need to transpile via Babel or use `require`.

Comment: I am using webpack in the project where i've moved these components from. It for some whatever reason does not want to load these with the webpack loaders though.

Comment: Your webpack loader probably only transpiles local files, not `node_modules`.